# How do I find out which (page) template file my custom child post is looking for?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, page-template, wp-insert-post, child-pages

I am trying to make something like a web-app with WP. One of the issues I'm facing now is that I cannot find out which page template file my post is looking for. I have looked at template file hierarchy etc. but to no avail. Don't really know which steps to follow from here so hoping there's someone that can help me.

I have made a custom post type called "week". When a week post is published, 7 days of the week, called "palaver" are also generated. These *palaver posts* are children of the *week post* and also inherit the custom taxonomy of the published *week post*. See the code below in my functions.php.

```
function create_days_week($new_status, $old_status, $post){
if ('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && $post->post_type === 'week'){
    $week = array(
    "0" => 'Saturday',
    "1" => 'Sunday',
    "2" => 'Monday',
    "3" => 'Tuesday',
    "4" => 'Wednesday',
    "5" => 'Thursday',
    "6" => 'Friday'
);

    $latestposts = new wp_query(array(
        'post_type' => 'week',
        'orderby'   => 'post_date',
        'order'     => 'desc',
        ));
    $latestpost = $latestposts->posts;
    $CategoryName = get_the_terms($latestpost[0]->ID, 'area');
    $CatTermID = array($CategoryName[0]->term_taxonomy_id, $CategoryName[1]->term_taxonomy_id);

     foreach ($week as $weekday) {
        $PostID = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_title'    => $latestpost[0]->post_title . ': ' . $weekday,
            'post_type'     => 'palaver',
            'post_parent'   => $latestpost[0]->ID,
            'post_content'  => ''
        ));
        wp_set_object_terms($PostID, $CatTermID, 'area');
        update_post_meta($PostID, '_wp_page_template', 'single-palaver.php' );      
     }
}} add_action('transition_post_status', 'create_days_week', 10, 3);
```

So this works fine (took a decent while to figure everything out though haha). When I look at palaver posts in the admin the posts are displayed as "— Week 1: Tuesday — Draft | Parent Page: Week 1". I'm not sure where the leading dash comes from, but since it does not show in the title or anything I have not really bothered to figure it out.

When the status is still draft the URL shows like this "/?post_type=palaver&p=1264&preview=true". The preview page is powered by my single-palaver.php template.

However when I publish the *palaver post* the url changes to  "/palavers/week-1/week-1-thursday/". Which is

[rewrite of slug -> palavers]/[week post]/[palaver post] 
or

[palaver post]/[parent page/post]/[child page/post].

**Post type & taxonomy registration**

```
    register_post_type('palaver', array(
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'palavers'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('area'),
    'public'=> true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
    'hierarchical' => 'true',
    'labels'=> array(
        'name' => 'Palavers',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new Palaver',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Palaver',
        'all_items' => 'All Palavers',
        'Singular name' => 'Palaver'
    )
));
```

Both Week and Palaver are exactly the same apart from name and labels.

```
register_taxonomy('area', array('week', 'palaver'), array('hierarchical' => true));
```

---

**What I tried**

**1.** I tried the following template name files:

- single-palaver-week-palaver.php
- single.php
- page.php
- taxonomy-palaver.php
- palaver.php

And several variations which seemed plausible.

**2.** I also tried to set the template file when generating the post:

```
update_post_meta($PostID, '_wp_page_template', 'single-palaver.php' );
```

**3.** I made a single *palaver* post which was recognized and after publication loaded from the single-palaver.php file. URL was /palavers/test.

**4.** I tried to add a filter in functions.php:

```
add_filter('page_template', function ($template) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_parent) {
        $template = locate_template(['single-palaver.php']);
    }
    return $template;
} );
```

If there is a parent page it could only be the palaver post so this should have worked, but did not.

**5.** I tried to get the page template slug:

```
<?php echo esc_html( get_page_template_slug( $post->ID ) ); ?>
```

However it seems that there are no posts at all to load so this also did not help.. :(

---

**What *is* shown?**

(1) In the "normal *published* palaver post" with the URL:/palavers/week-1/week-1-thursday/. My header and footer are loaded and it works of the *index.php* file. However, *The Loop* does not recognize the current (or any for that matter) post, so nothing is shown beyond that.

(2) When I go to the URL:/palavers something completely strange happens. The Loop recognizes the posts of type "palaver" but works off of 2(!) template files. First it goes through the complete single-palaver.php template file (inc. header and footer), after which it goes through the complete index.php file (again inc. header and footer).

**Ideal situation**

I'm not sure yet whether I'm going to need an archive for the palaver post type so (2) is not really a priority.

For (1) though I would like all my palaver posts (independent of whether they are children or not) to load the template file single-palaver.php.

I have the feeling that I tried everything but am missing something trivial. If anyone knows an answer or solution to this, or another avenue to explore, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If think you were using the wrong filter, please try using 'single_template'.

I assume you have created a plugin to create your custom post type. In the plugin folder you have a "templates" folder where you put the single page template called "palaver_single.php".

```
function palaver_single_mapping($single) {

global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type == 'palaver' ) {
        if ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/palaver_single.php' ) ) {
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/palaver_single.php';
        }
    }

    return $single;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'palaver_single_mapping' );
```

So if a single palaver post is viewed, the template file inside the templates folder will be used.

Comment: Hi Rank,

Thanks for your answer. I did not use a plugin to create my custom post types, my single-palaver.php is in the root of my theme folder. I did try to put the change of filter type to use by changing your code to look for the right templates, however it did not work unfortunately. 

I think this is due to the fact that the URL "/palavers/week-1/week-1-thursday/". doesn't find any type of post: checking if the *post_type* is 'palaver' does not work if no posts are found.. 

I'm going to try rewriting the URL with add_rewrite_rule. Might that work in your opinion?